# How to create form to update file using PHP?

Tags: php, string, file

I have written a PHP script which allows me to modify and update a file on a webpage, which works, but the script right now presents the entire contents of the file in a text area. I would like to extract just the string from the file and pre-populate it in a form text field (instead of a text area).

Below are the two files I need to update. I would like to just update the IP addresses. So the form would ideally show that mail.helloworld.com current maps to "208.164.222.2" and populate that IP address in a form text field. Same idea for the /etc/postfix/main.cf file as shown below.

/etc/hosts

IPAddress     Hostname             Alias
           127.0.0.1            localhost        deep.openna.com
           208.164.222.2        mail.helloworld.com      mail
           208.164.222.3        web.helloworld.com       web

/etc/postfix/main.cf

relayhost= 192.168.1.10

===

Current working script using textarea:

```
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
<textarea rows="13" cols="110" name="content">
<?
$fn = "/etc/postfix/main.cf";
print htmlspecialchars(implode("",file($fn)));

?> 
</textarea></br>
<input id= "relayhost_button" type="submit" value="Update"> 
</form> 



<?
$fn = "/etc/postfix/main.cf";
$content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);
$fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
fputs($fp,$content);
fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=done.php\" />\n";
?>
```

Here is the current textarea based form:

[image]

New text field based form I want:

[image]
As always, thanks folks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? Are you saying you want to present each line of the text file as a separate form field? Or do you want it to go further and parse the file further so that each line is split into the left side and right side of the IP address assignment?

Comment: I posted a picture of what I have vs what I need. The main reason for wanting to only show the IP as an editable field is that I don't want users to change other parameters such as the domain name. Right now the textarea script presents the users with the ability to update any section of the text file so it is prone to user mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the file, then present the wanted line to the user.  Once (s)he has edited it, reparse the file, and replace the information.  (Instead of parsing, you could just track which line number it was.)

Other than that, the question gets a bit in depth.  Do you have any specific problems?

Also, a few non-related suggestions:

- Replace the implode(file()) with file_get_contents.
- Use complete opening tags ('< ?php' without the space)
- Use fwrite instead of fputs (no actual justification for this one, I just avoid using aliases)
- A large part personal preference, but I find it cleaner to do redirects with headers than with meta tags.

Eg:

```
header("Location: http://blah/done.php");
```

Comment: Corbin, thanks for the tips.  The main reason for wanting to only show the IP as an editable field is that I don't want users to change other parameters such as the domain name. Right now the textarea script presents the users with the ability to update any section of the text file so it is prone to user mistakes. Any sample code would be appreciated or links to a resource is cool too. Thanks again.

Comment: Parse each line (either some creative exploding and trimming or preg_match with a pattern like /^([1-9][0-9]{0,2})\.([1-9][0-9]{0,2})\.([1-9][0-9]{0,2})\s+(.*?)/)  Then you would just present the user with the form with domain and IPs separated.  Then when they submitted the form, you would refind the domains and replace them.  Due to the variations of valid formats within text files, you may have some problems finding a 100% bullet proof parsing system.  Also, you'll need to either have your code aware of other users potentially making changes, or you'll need to lock the file.